# Oracle SGA_TARGET size

Tags: oracle, plsql

I set initialization parameter SGA_TARGET=430MB in initORACLE_SID.ora file. After started instance, I ran command ‘show parameters sga_target’, result was 432MB. Where did 2 MB come from? Is this due to the size of db_block_size(8192), If not, then what?

Comment: Plz provide version of oracle rdms and comand  did you start the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SGA allocations are all sized as a multiple of the SGA granule size, which depends on the Oracle version and the total size of the SGA.

You can find some details in the [ASMM documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/memory.htm#ADMIN11203). For small SGAs in 12c, the granule size is 4MB, which explains the rounding in your case. The `V$SGAINFO` view can be used to check this value too.